# Rails 4 stream a response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, streaming

I want to render some text at the beginning of the request, and then some other text at the end.

This is how I am trying to do it

```
class DevelopmentController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_login

  before_action { not_found! unless Rails.env.development? }

  def pry
    render text: 'Go to your server, a pry session awaits!', stream: true
    require 'pry'
    binding.pry
    render text: 'Pry session complete.'
  end
end
```

It gets upset with me because I called render twice: `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`

I have also tried writing directly to the stream, which works in the sense that it renders in the end, but it doesn't render the text before the pry until the request ends (ie not streaming):

```
def pry
  response.stream.write 'Go to your server, a pry session awaits!'
  require 'pry'
  binding.pry
  response.stream.write 'Pry Complete'
end
```

Thought maybe the stream needs to be flushed, but there's apparently no flush method on it, so IDK.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `include ActionController::Live` to be able to stream, it works fine with `sleep` but it didn't work with byebug for some reason, but you need to ensure that the connection is closed when you're done, otherwise it will stay open. here's an example

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live
  def stream
    100.times {
      response.stream.write "<p>#{Time.now}</p>"
      sleep 1
    }
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

The module is [documented here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html), for some reason when I added that header that's provided in the example it prompted a download instead of the stream.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work for me with sleep either :( I tried both with Chrome and curl, didn't see the response until it was all finished (ie 100 seconds later).

Comment: Not in this case, I did it exactly like yours (then lowered the number b/c 100seconds is a long time), then tried with their header and with the example from `ActionController::Live::SSE`. I was on Rails 4.2.0, though, IDK if that matters.

Comment: The link I provided adds a header, try adding that (I was testing on ff, maybe on chrome it needs that header)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, too, and verified that it wasn't committed at the time that the header was set, and checked headers on the client side to make sure they were actually being set. They are, but just don't get shipped out until the "stream" is closed. I guess I didn't try opening a raw socket, but I did pass the `--no-buffer` flag to curl, so I'd expect it to show results immediately.

Comment: try testing with firefox, just to make sure it's not something chrome specific